# Bind boolean to checkbox MVVM

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I am trying to bind a boolean through the viewmodel to the view, but Android Studio throws an error, and I can't find the problem. The viewModel.infilltype is a boolean, and android:checked should also be a boolean.

"error: '@{viewModel.infillType}' is incompatible with attribute android:checked (attr) boolean.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: '@{viewModel.infillType}' is incompatible with attribute android:checked (attr) boolean., sources=[E:\SportveldOnderhoud\app\src\main\res\layout\list_item_check.xml:14], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}"

I have the following code (I will paste snippets which are relevant)

Check.java  (Model)

```
public class Check {

    private UUID mId;
    private String mTitle;
    private Date mDate;
    ....
    private boolean mInfilltype;
    ....

    public Check() {
        this(UUID.randomUUID());
    }

    public Check(UUID id) {
        mId = id;
        mDate = new Date();
    }
    public UUID getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    ....

    public boolean isInfilltype() {
        return mInfilltype;
    }

    public void setInfilltype(boolean infilltype) {
        mInfilltype = infilltype;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CheckViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    private Check mCheck;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public CheckViewModel(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getTitle() {
        return mCheck.getTitle();
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getRenderedDate() {
        return mCheck.getDate().toString();
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean infillType() {
        return mCheck.isInfilltype();
    }

    public Check getCheck() {
        return mCheck;
    }

    public void setCheck(Check crime) {
        mCheck = crime;
        List<String> strings;
        notifyChange();
    }

    public void onCheckClicked() {
        Intent intent = CheckPagerActivity.newIntent(mActivity, mCheck.getId());
        mActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="nl.lekolkman.android.sportveldonderhoud.CheckViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onCheckClicked()}"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/solved_check_box"
            android:checked="@{viewModel.infillType}"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
            android:text="@{viewModel.title}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/solved_check_box"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Crime Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
            android:text="@{`Date solved: ` + viewModel.renderedDate ?? `(not solved)`}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/solved_check_box"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_text_view"
            tools:text="Check Date"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I had to add:

```
android { 
...
    dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
```

in build.gradle

Then it still didn't work however, but after adding maven to the repositories in the build.gradle files it did work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with java, but I'm pretty sure in C# your boolean needs an initial value (not null) to bind properly.

Try changing

```
private boolean mInfilltype;
```

to

```
private boolean mInfilltype = false;
```

Comment: by default they are initialized to false, if you declare the type as Boolean(object) you can assign it null if it's boolean (with lower case b) it's primitive and can hold only false/true

Answer (score 0):

You can use or expand Android Compound View Binding Adapter

```
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import androidx.databinding.BindingMethod;
import androidx.databinding.BindingMethods;
import androidx.databinding.InverseBindingListener;
import androidx.databinding.InverseBindingMethod;
import androidx.databinding.InverseBindingMethods;
import androidx.annotation.RestrictTo;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
/**
 * @hide
 */
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY)
@BindingMethods({
        @BindingMethod(type = CompoundButton.class, attribute = "android:buttonTint", method = "setButtonTintList"),
        @BindingMethod(type = CompoundButton.class, attribute = "android:onCheckedChanged", method = "setOnCheckedChangeListener"),
})
@InverseBindingMethods({
        @InverseBindingMethod(type = CompoundButton.class, attribute = "android:checked"),
})
public class CompoundButtonBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("android:checked")
    public static void setChecked(CompoundButton view, boolean checked) {
        if (view.isChecked() != checked) {
            view.setChecked(checked);
        }
    }
    @BindingAdapter(value = {"android:onCheckedChanged", "android:checkedAttrChanged"},
            requireAll = false)
    public static void setListeners(CompoundButton view, final OnCheckedChangeListener listener,
            final InverseBindingListener attrChange) {
        if (attrChange == null) {
            view.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
        } else {
            view.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onCheckedChanged(buttonView, isChecked);
                    }
                    attrChange.onChange();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/androidx/databinding/adapters/CompoundButtonBindingAdapter.java